# jQuery .index() start at 1 not 0?

Tags: jquery

Im returning the number of the element thats clicked with this:

```
$(".accordian li").click(function(){
    var accordianNo = $(this).index();
});
```

Is there a way I can make the numbers start at 1 not 0?

Comment: Index() starts from Zero

Comment: No. JS uses 0-based indices.

Comment: By adding `1` to the value reported by `index()`? But what *problem* is this meant to solve, or is it because you don't like counting from zero for some reason?

Comment: You can always add 1 if its really needed. You can also write a plugin that returns `index()+1` - like `$(this).indexFrom1()`.

Comment: Its important to know how you gona use `accordianNo`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add one to the variable.

```
$(".accordian li").click(function(){
    var accordianNo = $(this).index() + 1;
});
```